# Lexical Preprocessor issue (File not found)

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am developed my project in iOS 4.3 iOS. After that i am upgrade my Mac OSX 10.7 to 10.8. And installed **Xcode 4.5.1 (with 6.0 iOS).**

After that when i was open my project then it give me an error message as per mention in below image.

[image: Please see this image:]

Comment: I am also refer below link but issue remain same:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving

Answer (score 3):

CMSync is iOS 6. Check your target for your project

Comment: Have checked my project target was iOS 6.0

Comment: Have you checked the iOS Deployment Target, or the other iOS SDK setting (can't remember what it's called at the moment)

Comment: Oh, and make sure you do a Clean before the Build (this helps after changing iOS version sometimes too)

Comment: I did all the things but issue was remain exists. I am working on it from 1 day and i have try all way to solved this. :(

Comment: Remove the frameworks and then re-add them to ensure you have the correct versions