# build failed while archiving

Tags: ios

[image]i have almost completed  project using carousel view and it is running fine in simulator but,  while archiving it shows lexical or Processor Issue("CoreImage/coreImage.h file not found").  i tried trouble shoot this error with answers in these links 
**[Lexical Preprocessor issue (File not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932671/lexical-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found)**,
**[lexical or preprocessor issue file not found occurs while archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving)**
and added Quartzcore.framework checked in build settings even then it shows same error.
added code sign also .

Comment: can you please post the screenshot or comment here which you are getting

Comment: Did you link `CoreImage Framework`?

Comment: yes! i did and checked  in build phases also

Comment: Ensure that build settings are correct for the build configuration that you are using for archiving. Product->Edit Scheme->Archive to check for the Build Configuration.

Comment: sorry to bother  my Xcode is corrupted. I figured it by archiving my previous project which already archived thanks you for support

Comment: updated Xcode it fixed my issue