# Phonegap 3.5 + Facebook Plugin error It says "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h file not found"

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to port a Phonegap App from 2.3 to 3.5 .

I created a new clean project using Phonegap 3.5 . Added iOS platform and added the plugins. I added the Phonegap Facebook Plugin as indicated in the [Plugin Page](https://github.com/aogilvie/phonegap-facebook-plugin) :

```
cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

The plugin added itself ok, or at least that's what it seems. When I opened the project in XCode, it doesn't build, it reports a Lexical or Preprocessor error that it cannot find file FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h .

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I made the error go away but I am not sure if what I did is correct.

Under Frameworks, all frameworks have Headers folder with the .h files. In the case of the FacebookSDK.framework, Headers was a file with a path to a folder ./Versions/A/Headers . I manually copied the content of Versions/A folder under the FacebookSDK.framework folder. Now it finds the FacebookSDK.h file.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065666/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-facebooksdk-facebooksdk-h-file-not-found

Comment: Thank you. Those solutions did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the phonegap plugin facebook through a locally cloned copy and also re-add the FacebookSDK.framework to Xcode after installation, but none of this worked to me. The way I solved was installing https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.

1. Remove the phonegap plugin:
   ionic plugin rm phonegap-facebook-plugin
2. Clone the next plugin git clone: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git
3. Add the plugin manually: cordova -d plugin add PATH/cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="*****" --variable APP_NAME="*****"

Thats how it works to me.