# Error importing framework on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios

I've added an external framework to my project. It builds on simulator(s) just fine (iPhone simulator 3.5 inch, iPhone simulator 4 inch, iPhone simulator 4 inch(64-bit)). I've tried to build it for my iPhone 5s and it gives me '**Lexical or preprocessor Issue LibName/HeaderName.h file not found.**'.

I've successfully built the project without the framework previously - which makes me think it's not about the project settings. And I've also used this framework in other projects - which makes me think it's not about the framework. Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lexical or preprocessor issue file not found occurs while archiving?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925539/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-occurs-while-archiving)

Comment: Which framework is it?

Comment: @esqew How is this a duplicate? Framework builds perfectly on simulator and not on device?

Comment: @duci9y It's an inhouse framework, made by the company I work for.

Comment: @Mercurial If you had actually read the question I had linked, you would know that the other question talks about the same thing - a framework, building fine in the simulator, throws an error regarding a "Lexical or preprocessor issue".

Comment: @esqew Nope. It shows error while archiving and it works fine on both device and simulator, in the link you have posted.