# Lexixal or Preprocessor issue: 'iostream' file not found

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode5, sudoku, qqwing

I am trying to use **qqwing.h**, **qqwing.cpp** and **config.h** files in my project to create a sudoku game and I am getting below error.

[image: Error image]

I tried a lot of solutions by changing and setting different values in my project but nothing has solved my issue.

Please help!

Comment: Files in which I am importing qqwing.h have .mm extension.

Comment: Are you *certain* the file being compiled when that error occurs is a C++ or Objective-C++ source file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10925539/1938163

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually the issue was not for the compiler, it was because one of my required file was having .m extension instead it should be .mm.